# Visul Studio 2022 with Visual Assist - GO button gets huge issue

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-assist

I am using:

- current version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.4.3.
- current version of Visual Assist (Visual Assist build 2022.5)

I have a random problem, when `Go` button sometimes after pressing some function with `ctrl` + `right click` (go to implementation) gets huge.

How it looks like:
[image]

How it should look like:
[image]

The only solution which makes it smaller again is to close Visual Studio and reopen it again. I have already tried with no success:

- Disable Visual Assist and reenable it
- `ctrl` + `scroll` in many places

Comment: Problem was reported to Whole Tomato and was also reported by other users.
https://forums.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=20427

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved in the recent update of Visual Assist